# fill specific cells in second column - vba excel

Tags: vba, excel

This is my code:

```
Sub fillcells()   

     Dim rngA As Range                  
     Dim arrayFinal As Variant                  
     Dim i As Long                  

     For Each rngA In Range("A:A") 

        If rngA.Value Like "*-*" Then         
            Debug.Print True         
            ' Split range A value into an array                 
            arrayFinal = Split(rngA.Value, "-")               
            'add n rows below the cells containig "-"                     
            rngA.Offset(1, 0).Resize(UBound(arrayFinal)).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown         
            For i = LBound(arrayFinal) To UBound(arrayFinal)         
                rngA.Offset(i, 0).Value = arrayFinal(i)         
            Next i   
      End If
     Next rngA  

End Sub
```

**Editor note:** the code is wrong since the `If` is inside a `For` loop but end (`End If`) after it (`Next rngA`)! Is it a typo or a mistake?

On the sheet I have 2 filled columns(A and B). My code loop column A and check the cells containing "-" character. If it finds it, adds a new row below that cell and fills it with the string after "-" from column A. 
But my problem is this: in column B I have much empty rows that I created before. I want to fill them with the strings over empty rows, from column B. How can I do that?

to be more specific, for example:

```
         column B   

row1:    hello1         
row2:    (empty)         
row3:    (empty)                  
row4:    hello2         
row5:    hello3         
row6:    hello4         
row7:    (empty)      
row8:    hello5                     
...         
rown:    .....
```

and what I want is this:

```
row1:    hello1         
row2:    hello1         
row3:    hello1                 
row4:    hello2         
row5:    hello3         
row6:    hello4         
row7:    hello4      
row8:    hello5                     
...         
rown:    .....
```

What I need is an optimized code, so I have to use (if possible) the same loop because I have many filled rows.

Comment: sorry, yes...it was a typo. I have amended the code. thnks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have modified your code (see below) to give you one way of doing what you want. It may not be the best way, but at least it'll give you an idea about what you can do.

```
Sub fillcells()

  Dim rngA As Range
  Dim rngB As Range ' <~~ NEW CODE
  Dim arrayFinal As Variant
  Dim i As Long

  For Each rngA In Range("A:A")

    If rngA.Value Like "*-*" Then
      Debug.Print True
      ' Split range A value into an array
      arrayFinal = Split(rngA.Value, "-")
      'add n rows below the cells containig "-"
      rngA.Offset(1, 0).Resize(UBound(arrayFinal)).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown
      For i = LBound(arrayFinal) To UBound(arrayFinal)
        rngA.Offset(i, 0).Value = arrayFinal(i)
      Next i
    End If

    ' NEW CODE STARTS HERE
    Set rngB = rngA.Offset(0, 1)
    If rngA.Value <> vbNullString And rngB.Value = vbNullString Then
      rngB.Value = rngB.Offset(-1, 0).Value
    End If
    ' NEW CODE ENDS HERE

  Next rngA

End Sub
```

To start with, I added a new Range variable (`rngB`). Then, I set it as a single column offset from `rngA`. Finally, if the cell column A has some text but in column B it's **empty**, then I **copy** the value of the **previous row in column B** to the **current row in column B**. And all within your existing loop, as you wanted.

Comment: wow...thank you! Your idea is very good. I didn't think in this way. Thanks!

Comment: if possible, can I ask you something else? How can I get the value of column B(the value I've copied before) and divide it into split cells value? The first row must be modified too. Thank you for your feedback and patience.

Comment: @musiclandia: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. There's a Split function you can use to split a delimited string. If your requirements are more complex than that, it's probably better if you ask a new question for people to help you.

Comment: I just want to divide the values from column B into the empty cells number occurrence and fill empty cells with number divided. But, thank you anyway. I'll try to work something out.